# Views: Show only "Grouping Field" headings

Tags: views, 8

I'm working on customizing a view that is displaying a content type. I need to build an attachment that shows available taxonomy terms on this content type.

In this attachment, I currently have the taxonomy term name displaying as a field for each returned instance of the content type.

Grouping the results by the taxonomy name field produces one instance of each term as an `<h3>` followed by one instance for each node that was returned:

```
TAXONOMY TERM 1 (Grouping Title, H3)
    taxonomy term 1 (term on node)
    taxonomy term 1 (term on node)
    taxonomy term 1 (term on node)
TAXONOMY TERM 2 (Grouping Title, H3)
    taxonomy term 2 (term on node)
    taxonomy term 2 (term on node)
    taxonomy term 2 (term on node)
```

Is there a way to just show the grouping without outputting the additional content? Something like:

```
TAXONOMY TERM 1 (Grouping Title, H3)
TAXONOMY TERM 2 (Grouping Title, H3)
```

This would produce exactly what I need but I can't figure out a good way to do this.

I've tried aggregation but this makes exposed filter inheritance for the attachment messy and unreliable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display all the terms  possible, and not only those assigned to nodes, it doesn't make sense to build it through a Node View.

You can create a new View of type Taxonomy terms, create a block displaying Taxonomy terms, then place the Block in the Content region on your Views page (or any other region).

Alternatively you could also use a module to create the block listing Taxonomy terms: [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and again place the Block in a region and restrict it to show only on your node View page.